# Access Denied - CreateDirectory C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, impersonation

I have an ASP.NET application that has a button. When you click the button it has one line where is creates a sub-directory in a directory I have Read, Write, Modify through an AD group on another server (NOT the web server).

When I click the button I get an Access Denied error to the sub-directory.

Impersonate is set to true in the web.config.

Authentication is Windows.

WindowsIdentity is set to me.

The application is running under my account because of the above two things.

I can click the button and have it open the folder in Windows Explorer. So I have access to the parent.

If I create a subfolder in the folder. I can click the button and have it open the subfolder in Windows Explorer

I can do all this using C# code.

Only when I try to create a subfolder using C# does it tell me Access Denied. But I have Read, Write and Modify permissions.

Do not understand why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try granting permission to the `sysname\iis_wpg` group.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IIS are you running?

Check the identity which is running the website in the application pool section. Verify that identity has the proper permissions on that directory. That is the identity which is being used to do the OS work.

Note that you might need to grant the identity in 7/7.5 via the command line on the directory such as

```
icacls c:\inetpub\wwwroot /grant "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)(RX)
```

see [Icalcs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) documentation.